# Why does this assembly code show 2 different colours?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I've compiled this with nasm, and i'm running it through bochs. In my mind the 2 colour variable should make it print the 2 lines in blue. It actually prints one brown and one white. I cannot figure it out though. Any help immensely appreciated

```
    [BITS 16]   
    [ORG 0x7C00]
    main:

    ;set video mode
    mov ah,0x00     ;function ref
    mov al,0x10     ;param - video mode
    int 0x10

    mov si, TestString
    mov bl,Color        ; Normal text attribute
    call PutStr

    mov si, TestString
    mov bl,Color2       ; Normal text attribute
    call PutStr

    jmp $

    ;-------------------------------- End of running code

    PutStr:
    ; Set up the registers for the interrupt call
    mov ah,0x0E         ; The function to display a chacter (teletype)
    mov bh,0x00         ; Page number

    .nextchar:
    lodsb               ; load string byte from SI into AL and increments SI
    or al,al            ; check for end of string
    jz .endofstring     ; jump to end if null

    int 0x10            ; Run the BIOS video interrupt 
    jmp .nextchar       ; Loop back round to the top

    .endofstring:
    ret


    Color db 0001b
    Color2 db 0001b
    TestString db 'Hello world',13,10,0,0

    times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Fill the rest of the sector with zero's
    dw 0xAA55           ; Add the boot loader signature to the end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually with the usage of the Color and Color2 identifier. You need to "dereference" them to get the actual value of what they "point" to:

```
mov bl, [Color]
```

Check out [Effective Addresses](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.01/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3) in the NASM manual for more information.

Comment: yeah, i changed it to: Color db 1b Color2 db 1b, I had to keep the db or it throws an error but it makes no difference. I know if I put the value into the mov as you suggest "mov bl, 1b" it work fine but I'm trying to understand how variables work so it's not really a solution for me. Thanks anyway though

Comment: What i mean is neither "Color db 1" or "Color db 00000001b" change the colour to blue. They are bright pink and red regardless of what i seem to put as the value.

Comment: no further ideas? it's driving me nuts!! thanks again for trying though.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. I'll change the answer

Answer (score 1):

`db` allocates a byte of memory and sets the symbol to be the address of that memory (hence the need to dereference it).

If you just want a symbolic name for a constant value, use `equ`:

```
Color equ 0001b
...
mov bl, Color
...
```